# How to add a custom Avatar component into an Input component to upload an image

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, avatar

```
<Input
    label="Avatar"
    placeholder="Avatar"
    className={classes.textField}
    inputComponent={
        <Avatar className={classNames(classes.avatar, classes.bigAvatar)}>
            {(this.state.user.firstName).charAt(0)}
        </Avatar>
    }
    type='file' 
    margin="normal"
    onChange={event => this.handleUploadImage(event.target.value)}/>
```

I want to add an Avatar component with which an image can be uploaded when I click on it.
But I don't know how?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough.

Comment: If you intent to use the avatar as a trigger to initiate the file selection: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/9716